# Xamarin доступ к MergedDictionaries из кода

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, style, resources

Есть страница, в ней подключаются стили через xaml таким образом:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <themes:MainStyles />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Сам словарь выглядит так:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                x:Class="MyMobApp.Themes.MainStyles">

<OnPlatform x:Key="BaseFont" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
    <On Platform="Android" Value="cuprum_standard.ttf#Cuprum" />
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="Cuprum" />
    <On Platform="UWP, WinRT, WinPhone" Value="Assets/Fonts/cuprum_standard.ttf#Cuprum" />
</OnPlatform>

<Style x:Key="Grey" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource BaseFont}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#A0A0A0" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="h1" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#000000" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource BaseFont}" />
</Style>
```

В XAML применяю стили так:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Date}" Margin="10,10,10,0" HeightRequest="13" Style="{StaticResource Grey}" />
```

Всё работает. Но затем появилась необходимость добавлять на страницу динамически Label, к которым нужно прилепить стиль Grey, например. 
Погуглил и нашел такой вполне логичный вариант:

```
this.Wrapper.Children.Add(new Label
        {
            Text = this._Event.Date,
            Style = Application.Current.Resources["Grey"] as Style
        });
```

НО он выбрасывает исключение `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Склоняюсь к тому, что в моём случае не просто Resource, а дело в MergedDictionaries. Как в таком случае применить стиль из кода C#?

Comment: есть неплохой (как минимум) сайт Метанит :) см. [установку динамических/статических ресурсов в коде C#](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/9.2.php)

Comment: @Alias Спасибо за наводку, но я знаю этот ресурс, смотрел, и там немного не то. Мне нужно получить доступ не к конкретному единичному свойству (типа Color), а к набору Setter'ов именуемый стилем, т.е. к стилям в словаре.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Моё предположение касательно MergedDictionaries оказалось верно. Но я не понимал, что несмотря на то, что словарь подключен в XAML, работая с ним из кода его нужно дополнительно подключать. Я сделал так:

1. Подключил пространство где лежит словарь со стилями `using MyMobApp.Themes`;
2. Инициализировал новый ресурс `this.Resources = new ResourceDictionary();`
3. Добавил в него свой словарь как MergedDictionaries `Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new MainStyles());`
4. При создании Label применил стиль из своего словаря

   ```
   this.Wrapper.Children.Add(new Label
           {
               Text = this._Event.Date,
               Style = Resources["Grey"] as Style
           });
   ```

**ADD:** Если мержить словари нет необходимости (используете один, например), инициализируем объект ресурса только одним своим словарём вот так:  `this.Resources = new MainStyles();` и далее по схеме выше.